# The distribution of the attribute vs the measuring tool?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

Assume an attribute is normally distributed. 
Assume we sample from the top 5% of that distribution.
Assume we measure the attribute with a multiple-choice test.
Assume the difficulty level of the m/c test is such that the average difficulty is p=.5

The scores on the m/c test will tend to be normally distributed due to the test score being based on the binomial distribution.

But the underlying attribute is not normally distributed in the population we are sampling from (since the population for the sake of this quesion is the top 5% of a normal distribution).

Will the data reflect the tail of the normal distribution that we are sampling from, or will the data reflect a normal distribution due to the m/c measuring tool?

Comment: Re: "The scores on the m/c test will tend to be normally distributed:" be careful here.  The scores attained *by a given individual, upon independent repetitions of the test,* may well be approximated by a Normal distribution provided the test has enough independent questions.  But this says *nothing at all* about how the scores will vary from one individual to another!

Comment: @whuber  Do you care to comment on the simulation in BruceET's answer?

Comment: BruceET remarked that his simulation "validat[es] @whuber's cautionary comment."  I agree--and you don't need to know `R` to appreciate its implications: just look at the histogram. One can obtain even more convincing results by recognizing that your question doesn't stipulate that the score on the test is a linear function of the underlying attribute (an assumption unlikely to be true in most applications, anyway). It is therefore possible that the spread in scores among the top 5% could be extremely skewed.

Comment: For an actual example of that, see the statistics on top-scoring individuals in the annual [Putnam competition.](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/putnam2017stats.html)

Comment: @whuber  The Putnam problems are not true-false or multiple-choice questions, so the highest Putnam scores do not shed light on the question I pose above.

Comment: On the contrary, it does.  For one thing, the multiple choice nature of your question is a red herring.  For another, it is rare for the Putnam problems to receive scores other than 0-1 or 8-10, which makes their total scores act--to a very good approximation--like those of a multiple choice test. Besides, the only reason to allude to the Putnam was to demonstrate that the result obtained by BruceET's simulation is not artificial: it echoes scores one can observe in comparable circumstances.

Comment: @whuber. If mathematical cognitive ability is distributed like other human abilities, it is roughly normal in distribution in the population at large.  Why would the top scoring test takers have scores that are roughly normally distributed, as in the simulation?

Comment: You misread the simulation results: that histogram is intended to exhibit *non* normality, not normality!  The boxplot helps you see the positive skew in it.  The top scores in the Putnam competition exhibit a more extreme example of such skewness.

Comment: @whuber  Pardon my lack of insight, but what part of the link you provided (https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/putnam2017stats.html) shows a normal distribution of the scores for the top 502 contestants?

Comment: It shows a *non* normal distribution!

Comment: @whuber. The histogram in the simulation may be somewhat skewed, but it is far from reflective of the distribution of the extreme high tail of a normal distribution.

Comment: That is true, because what you are looking at is a combination of the right tail, the transformation from its value to the test score, and the random variation in the test score.  The latter will tend to reduce the skewness.

Comment: @whuber. That brings us back to my question, "Will the data reflect the tail of the normal distribution that we are sampling from, or will the data reflect a normal distribution due to the m/c measuring tool?"  I am interested in looking at the underlying distribution the human ability and not be misled by the distribution of the measurement tool.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @whuber. "Tend to reduce the skewness" is a huge understatement.  The distribution seen in the simulation is far from the shape of the high end tail of a normal distribution.  The mode in the simulation is near the center of the histogram rather than being at the extreme left.

Comment: Yes to the penultimate comment--but it requires you to specify how the underlying attribute is associated with the test score and, more importantly, to make a gross simplifying assumption that the questions are independent: that is, the answers given by any given individual to two different multiple choice questions will vary randomly and independently.  That's usually not the case, because various questions assess the same aspect of ability on most tests.  Re your last comment, it all depends on the parameters set in the simulation: why not experiment yourself?

Comment: @whuber. What might account for the Putnam data looking roughly like the top tail of a normal curve (strongly skewed to the high end) and the simulation looking roughly normal.

Comment: A natural hypothesis for the strong skew in the Putnam is that the translation from your hypothetically Normally-distributed "mathematical problem solving ability" to the test score is highly nonlinear: simply put, the questions are designed to exaggerate tiny differences in ability among contestants, with the exaggeration increasing with ability. Another way to say this is that if you take the expected score on this exam to be proportional to the attribute of interest, then that attribute has an extremely skewed--and very non-normal--distribution in the population.

Comment: @whuber  Might the near normal distributions that we see for mental abilities be due to the multiple-choice (correct-incorrect) nature of the tests we use to measure those abilities, rather than due to the underlying mental abilities being normally distributed?

Comment: Certainly that's part of it.  Another part, and perhaps the most important, is by construction: many test scores are adjusted to produce a normal distribution of results (assuming future examinees are similar to previous ones).

Comment: @whuber The cognitive ability tests that some to mind score the questions as right or wrong and give equal credit to each question.  What tests did you have in mind when you wrote "adjusted to produce a normal distribution"?

Comment: The best known are IQ tests.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you intend that those at the upper end of the
attribute scale will do better on the exam.
One simple and direct way to model this is to take the attribute to be the
probability $p$ of success on each of 100 T/F exam questions.

Suppose there are 20,000 potential
subjects with $p \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0.5, \sigma=0.1).$
Then we pick the top 1000 of them (5%). The score of the $i$th
participant is taken to be $X_i \sim \mathsf{Binom}(100, p_i),$
for $i = 1, 2, \dots, 1000.$

I have no idea whether this is a realistic model, but it might be
a starting point towards clarifying what kind of model you have in mind. [If the attribute is precisely exam-taking ability, a beta distribution for $p$ might be a better choice than normal.]

```
set.seed(603)
p = sort(rnorm(20000, .5, .1), decr=T)[1:1000]
s = rbinom(1000, 100, p)
hist(s, prob=T)
summary(s)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  56.00   66.00   70.00   70.25   74.00   93.00 

tab = cbind(p,s)
head(tab)
             p  s  # scores of 6 highest 'attribute' subj
[1,] 0.9222469 89
[2,] 0.9020532 90
[3,] 0.8966595 93
[4,] 0.8706467 85
[5,] 0.8425157 85
[6,] 0.8409540 87

tail(tab)
                p  s   
 [995,] 0.6655590 68    # ...and of 6 lowest
 [996,] 0.6655020 67
 [997,] 0.6653522 62
 [998,] 0.6653462 74
 [999,] 0.6652848 74
[1000,] 0.6652532 61
```

Although the mean and median scores are nearly the same (both around 70), the
histogram and the boxplot of the 1000 simulated scores both show some right-skewness--as you anticipated. A Shapiro-Wilk tests rejects the null hypothesis that the scores are normal (validating @whuber's cautionary comment).

```
 shapiro.test(x)$p.val
 [1] 0.001612833
```

[image]

The right-hand panel below shows a scatterplot of scores against success probabilities.

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
 boxplot(s, col="skyblue2", pch=20, main="Boxplot of Score")
 plot(p, s, pch=",")
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: TY for doing this simulation.  Please bear with me as my ability to read R is limited.  Does the histogram show the distribution of the simulated scores of the people in the top 5% of the normal distribution?  If so, it supports my fear that the distribution of those scores overwhelmingly reflects the binomial nature of the true-false test rather than the distribution of the underlying ability (i.e., a truncated normal distribution).  Does that correctly describe what you found?

Comment: For probabilities above 1/2 binomial dist'ns are left skewed, so it seems to me that the right skewness of this histogram reflects the right skewed character of the upper tail (5%) of the 'attribute' distribution. The scatterplot shows that the $p$'s are right-skewed. // If I can help with understanding the R code, please ask about specific lines you're having trouble with. Vectors `p` and `s` each have 1000 elements. Notation `[1:1000]` can be read "such that indices are between 1 and 1000."